# Including js files into the files which are loaded with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working on my localhost with the latest (2.1.0) jQuery library.

First, I have a page named `index.php` and I load `video.php` into it. Also, `index.php` has the `javaengine.js` file which contains all the javascript codes of my website. But when I load `video.php` into `index.php`, I see that the js file isn't active on the loaded page. And I want to bring the codes all together in that file.

So, I need this `javaengine.js` to be included in `video.php` too.

I don't actually know how to do it or what to do about this.
Here are some parts of my `video.php`:

```
<?php

//here is for checking if this page is requested by jquery or others.
if(!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) && strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"])=="xmlhttprequest"){

?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I have to put these necessary javascript codes in here, because when I bring them out to `javaengine.js`, they don't work for this loaded page.

Also I load `video.php` into `index.php` by using this code:

```
$("#container").load("/video.php");
```

So, yes; my `index.php` has a div with a "container" id.

Comment: How are you loading video.php into index.php?  Post that code, please.

Comment: @user1477388 Alright, here you are. :)

Comment: i don't see a <script> tag pointing to javaengine.js like you have for jQuery...

Comment: @dandavis As I wrote, it's in the index.php (where the video.php loads into).

Comment: well it shouldn't load first if it need jQuery that only comes from video.php...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are trying to load `<script>`s after the initial page has already loaded.  You can try to use jQuery's `$.getScript` to load it.

Try this:

```
// load php page
$("#container").load("/video.php");
// load javascript dependencies
$.getScript('/YOUR_PATH_TO/javaengine.js');
```

To make sure that it has been loaded, use Google Chrome, click F12, and go to the Network tab.  You can see the file being loaded after the call is made.